# Two different approaches to subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

Regarding subviews in ios, I have a view that covers the whole screen, then I create and import another view which is just a red square on top of it. I was wondering if there is any difference or advantadge between these two approaches:

Approach 1:

```
//set the view
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

//setTheSquareView
    CGRect firstFrame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 150);
    HypnosisView *firstView = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:firstView];
```

and approach 2:

```
//set the view
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

//setTheSquareView
    CGRect firstFrame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 150);
    HypnosisView *firstView = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [myView addSubview:firstView];
```

The only difference being that in the first case I add both views as subviews of the main property view whereas in the second case I add the second view as a subview of the first view. They look the same on screen.
Thanks

Comment: if your myView's frame is not same frame as your self.view, it will look different. Because the view's frame is adjusted as its direct parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in my opinion that on the first approach if you change any of (myView) constraints , firstFrame will not change but in the second approach it will.